# Search for the first occurrence of a keyword + print the next column in Linux

Tags: awk

Suppose I have a file like this:

```
d,e,c,g,v,c,w,r
g,c,d,c,s,c,g,r
d,y,c,w,t,g,c,f
```

Now I want to print the column (without the comma delimiter) which appears just after the first 'c' in each row.So my output will look like this

```
g
d
w
```

I have tried the code:

```
awk -F"," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "c") {print $(i+1)};}' filename
```

But in output I'm getting the columns which appears after each 'c'. I only want the column which appears after the first 'c' .
How to solve the problem preferably using **awk**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `break`....

Comment: ... to terminate the for-loop `print $(i+1); break`

Comment: What if c is the last column?

Comment: You said `first occurrence of a keyword` in your subject - note "key**word**". If the columns in your real data and the target string can be more than single characters then update your example to show that since negating a multi-char string is a very different problem to solve than negating a single char and so most answers you have so far won't apply. Also included cases where a line has no `c`, where `c` is the first char, and where `c` is the last char on the line.

Answer (score 6):

A `sed` solution:

```sh
sed -n 's/[^c]*c,\([^,]\).*/\1/p' filename
```

[RegEx101 running this](https://regex101.com/r/ybKtmF/1)

Comment: as far as I know, `[^c]*` won't make any difference here as it can match zero times as well

Comment: @Sundeep `[^c]*c` makes a big difference. It warrant to match the very first `c` column only. Without it, `sed` would capture at the last `c` column. (tested wit Gnu `sed` version 4.7).

Comment: oops, my mistake, I forgot that this is substitution.. I was thinking in terms of line match when I made the comment.. so this solution would work only for single character columns

Answer (score 5):

Use awk keyword `next` to skip to next line after the first found "c" on each line:

```
$ awk -F"," '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i == "c") {print $(i+1);next};}' filename
g
d
w
```

Answer (score 4):

Considering that per line only one `c` will come. Could you please try following. This doesn't require loop + it will look for small or capital letter c here in lines.

```
awk 'match($0,/[cC],[^,]*/){
  print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-2)
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using function named `match` here where I am mentioning regex to match from small/capital character then comma after it to till next occurrence of comma here. If this regex is having matched value then variables named RSTART and RLENGTH will be set. Where RSTART tells starting of regex and RLENGTH tells total length of matched regex. Taking these values printing sub-string here from current line.

Answer (score 1):

with GNU awk:

```
awk '{split($2,array,","); print array[2]}' FS="c" file
```

Output:

```
g
d
w
```

I used awk's field separator (`FS`) to split row with `c` in two parts (`$1` and `$2`). With `split` I split second part (`$2`) then with `,` in multiple parts in an array (`array`) and printed second element.

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
$ awk -F'c,' '{ print $2 }' < filename |cut -d, -f1
g
d
w
```

Answer (score 1):

With [ripgrep](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```
$ rg -No 'c,([^,]+).*' -r '$1' ip.txt
g
d
w

$ # if you only want to match whole column
$ rg -No '(^|,)c,([^,]+).*' -r '$2' ip.txt
g
d
w
```

- `-N` to disable line number prefix in output
- `([^,]+)` to capture the column content
- `.*` match everything after to avoid multiple matches in a line
- `-r '$1'` replace matched portion with only content of capture group
- `(^|,)` to ensure only whole column is matched

Answer (score 0):

The `sed` / RegEx answer would be something like

```
sed 's/[^c]*,c,\([^,]*\),.*/\1/' filename > outfile
```

Should also work for multi-character entries.

Comment: Prints all line if line contains no `c`

Answer (score 0):

A perl one:

```
perl -pe 's/^.*?c,(.).*/\1/g,' filename
```

If it is not guaranteed that the input contains a `c` on every line, then this version will filter out any lines that do not:

```
perl -ne 'if (/c/) {s/^.*?c,(.).*/\1/g,; print}' filename
```

Comment: Prints all line if line contains no `c`

Comment: @LéaGris The question rather assumed that there will be a `c` on every line, but in response to your comment I added a version which will exclude any lines that do not.